# Can't publish comment post via Facebook Api 2.3

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Today, I can't publish comment post via Facebook Api Version 2.3. I get this error message.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "FyX+WKb5pvC"
  }
}
```

I'm tring to publish comment by posting "message" with Graph API Explorer.
[image]

Previous I can publish comment to post via Facebook Api.

**UPDATE**
I can do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Unsupported post request` usually means that you don´t have access to the endpoint. Compare those two IDs from your update and post, they even look different.